# Hallar el maximo con vectores de tipo char

Tags: c++

Una empresa que fabrica pantalones nos encargó procesar los resultados de una encuesta realizada a la población con referencia a la predilección de color de los pantalones ('N'=negro, 'A'=azul, 'B'=blanco, 'O'=otros).
Para ello se ingresan los siguiente datos para cada encuesta efectuada:

- Edad del encuestado (entre 1 y 99)
- Color elegido (N, A, B, O)
- Sexo(M o F)

El fin del lote se indica con un registro con edad igual a cero. Se pide determinar e informar:
El color más votado entre las mujeres.
Por cada década de edad, la cantidad de encuestados.

Década     Edad
0                1-9
1            10-19
2            20-29
…             …
9            90-99

No estoy logrando sacar el maximo color del sexo femenino
aca paso mi codigo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int edad;
    char color,sexo;
    /// A)
    char colorMujeres[4]={};
    int max=0;
    char maxColor;
    cout<<"Edad: "<<endl;
    cin>>edad;

    while(edad!=0)
    {
     cout<<"Color elegido ('N'=negro, 'A'=azul, 'B'=blanco, 'O'=otros)"<<endl;
     cin>>color;
     cout<<"Sexo(M o F)"<<endl;
     cin>>sexo;
     /// A)
     if(toupper(sexo)=='F')
     {
        colorMujeres[color]++;

     }
     for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
        {
            if(colorMujeres[x]>max)
            {
                max=colorMujeres[x];
                maxColor=color;
            }

     cout<<"Edad: "<<endl;
     cin>>edad;
    }
    /// A)
    cout<<"El color mas votado fue "<<maxColor<<", con la cantidad de "<<max<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

https://pastebin.com/Y3dg29FL

Cada vez que muestro el maxColor por pantalla no me da nada :(, alguna idea de como encararlo?

Comment: El codigo debe ir en tu pregunta,  no en enlaces externos. [edit] tu pregunta o de lo contrario puede quedar cerrada.

Comment: Se me ocurre que puedes contar cuántas veces aparece cada color y averiguar el máximo en base a esas cuentas.

Answer (score 1):

El usuario puede introducir los siguientes colores: `N`, `B` `A` y `O`

Así que tu has decidido crear un array de 4 elementos:

```
char colorMujeres[4]={};
```

Pero en ningún momento has hecho un *mapeo* que permita relacionar cada una de esas 4 posiciones del array con cada uno de los colores.

Si miras cualquier tabla ASCII verás que a cada caracter le corresponde una secuencia numérica. En el caso que nos ocupa los valores son los siguientes:

| color | valor |
| --- | --- |
| N | 78 |
| A | 65 |
| B | 66 |
| O | 80 |

Si tu usas estos valores tal cual, el programa intentará acceder a posiciones que claramente no pertenecen al array. Estarás, por tanto, accediendo a posiciones de memoria que pueden pertenecer a otras variables. Esto provoca que tu programa no funcione correctamente.

Hay varias formas de resolver este problema. Por ejemplo, puedes optar por hacerlo todo a mano. Para ello necesitas hacer un mapeo para asignar a cada color una posición del array

```
constexpr size_t POS_NEGRO  0;
constexpr size_t POS_AZUL   1;
constexpr size_t POS_BLANCO 2;
constexpr size_t POS_OTROS  3;

size_t get_pos_array(char color)
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case 'N':
        return POS_NEGRO;
    case 'A':
        return POS_AZUL;
    case 'B':
        return POS_BLANCO;
    case 'O':
        return POS_OTROS;
    default:
        /* ERROR */
}
```

Una vez que ya has hecho la asignación tienes los mimbres necesarios para escribir en el array de forma segura:

```
 cin>>color;
 size_t index = get_color_index(color);
 colorMujeres[index]++;
```

Eso si, nota que como `colorMujeres` es un array de tipo `char` no va a ser capaz de almacenar valores superiores a 255.

Otra opción, mucho más limpia, pasa por usar un contenedor de la STL. En este caso podrías usar `std::map`:

```
std::map<char, int> colorMujeres;
```

Ahora ya si puedes meterle los caracteres directamente al mapa, ya que éste se encarga de resolver el problema de asignar una posición a cada valor:

```
 cin>>color;
 colorMujeres[color]++;
```

El "problema" lo tendremos a la hora de mostrar los resultados, pues ya no tenemos un array sino un objeto. Aun así, elegir el color más votado no es complicado:

```
char maxColor;
int max = 0;

for (auto const& pair : colorMujeres)
{
    if (pair.second > max)
    {
        // Asignamos los valores a mano
        max = pair.second;
        maxColor = pair.first;

        // Esta línea hace lo mismo que las dos anteriores
        std::tie(maxColor, max) = pair;
    }
}
```

Para entender el código anterior basta con saber que `std::map` guarda pares de elementos. La clave será el primer elemento `first` del par mientras que el valor será el segundo elemento `second`.

A partir de C++17 podrías incluso explotar la tupla directamente en el bucle:

```
for (auto const& [key, val] : colorMujeres)
{
    if (val > max)
    {
        max = val;
        maxColor = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola lo saque asi if(toupper(sexo)=='F')
     {
        switch(color)
     {
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            colorMujeres[0]++;
            break;
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            colorMujeres[1]++;

            break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            colorMujeres[2]++;
            break;
        case 'o':
        case 'O':
            colorMujeres[3]++;
 break}  } use de ejemplo el swicth que me pasaste, pero aun soy nuevo y no se muy bien que significan algunas cosas que usaste como el map y objetos que aun no llegue a ver eso

Comment: Al final me dio el color maximo, pero si el usuario ingresara 50 tipos de colores tendria que sacarlo todo a mano y no se como aplicar de esa forma el vector

Comment: @Alexis_Rojas21 No deberías emplear valores _hardcoded_ tipo `colorMujeres[1]` en el código. Eso hace que el código sea dificil de mantener y de mejorar

Comment: De todas formas, si tienes N valores, el vector lo deberías iterar de 0 a N-1 para encontrar el valor más alto